# getting rid of space with the superscript in html emails

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

superscript is leaving a big space between the line height.

code is

```
<span style="position:relative; bottom:0.2em; font-size: 0.8em">&reg;</span>
```

I am not using the `<sup></sup>` tag as it too leaves a big gap in the line height.

Is there a work around. I am aware that the `position:relative` does not render well in outlook. What's the other alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made few experiments in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/RsqPF/) and I think you will be able to use:

```
<sup style="line-height: 0">&reg;</sup>
```

in firefox it does not increases the gap between the lines

Comment: That works fine on everything except OUTLOOK 2007 ON MAC :(. I think the <sup> tag keeps leaving a line height on this client

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by increasing  the `line-height` of the containing paragraph `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Outlook pads line-height when superscript is applied. One fix (with caveat!) is to do the following: 
apply

```
<style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
```

to the `<td>` IF there are no deviations in line-height in the cell **AND** no images used. **!!!(that's important because Outlook 2010 will cut off images if this is applied)** Then, apply

```
<span (or sup) style="font-size: (2px or more smaller than actual font size); line-height:0; vertical-align:3px;"
```

in the span tag wrapping the superscript.

SEE:  
http://emaildude.blogspot.com/2011/06/superscript-and-line-heights.html