# Superscript does not align in outlook 2011

Tags: html, css, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting rid of space with the superscript in html emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852086/getting-rid-of-space-with-the-superscript-in-html-emails)

Now this has been an issue for a while.

Can anyone fix the superscript leaving a big space in outlook 2011?

code is

```
<sup style="line-height:0; font-size:0.8em;">&reg;</sup>
```

It's particular to this client OUtlook 2011, works fine on the rest.

Comment: Try specifying a font size in pixels, not EMs.

Comment: @user544079 Please post a minimum screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by increasing the`line-height` of the containing paragraph `<p>`