# Superscript is messing up line height in HTML coded email. Can't figure out how to apply in-line CSS to resolve. Any tips? Code example inside

Tags: css, html-email

I'm trying to override the impact Superscript characters (registered trademark character ®) are causing to my email paragraph line height in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (using the HTML editor).

Here is an example of the paragraph I am attempting to apply the in-line CSS on:

```
 <span style="color:#569bbe;">&bull;</span> lorem palceholder text <sup>&reg;</sup> lorem lorem placeholder.<br>
```

I used the `<sup></sup>` tags, but that has caused line-height inconsistencies.

I found this example on a support forum:

```
sup { line-height: 0; font-size: 75%; }
```

But I'm clueless about where this code actually goes and what the proper syntax would be to implement it. I've tried a bunch of different areas, but most examples I'm finding are on webpage-oriented CSS structure and I'm attempting to do it in-line.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting rid of space with the superscript in html emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852086/getting-rid-of-space-with-the-superscript-in-html-emails)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out... Here is the solutuon:

```
<sup style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 5px;">&reg;</sup>
```